# proxy_set_header Hodst $host necessary for admin panel urls but messes up other wordpress urls

Tags: wordpress, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

## When I put

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

under location /wordpress/ in my nginx.conf-file, I get working Wordpress urls apart from the admin panel where /wordpress/ is removed from the urls, making all links in the admin panel non-functional.

If I remove proxy_set_header Host $host;, I get non-working Wordpress urls but a working admin-panel.

I run a Wordpress install with a NextJs front-end with docker-compose and an nginx reverse proxy in front of it. I need both working Wordpress urls and the admin panel because I need access to the RSS feed (the /feed-url which doesn't work when I do the proxy_set_header-thing).

### My location-block in nginx-conf:

```
 location /wordpress/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://IP-TO-WORDPRESS:8000/;
        # proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

### Tried

- adding and removing proxy_set_header Host $host,
- adding a special location block for wp-admin (/wordpress/wp-admin - didn't work)
- changing the url of proxy_pass
- changing siteurl and home in wp_options in the wordpress mysql database

### Entire Nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # worker_processes and worker_connections allows you to 
    calculate maxclients value:
    # max_clients = worker_processes * worker_connections
}

http{
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    # HTTPS ?~@~T proxy all requests to the Node app
    server {
        # Enable HTTP/2
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name SERVER-NAME.no;

        # Use the Let?~@~Ys Encrypt certificates
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/SERVER- 
        NAME.no/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/SERVER- 
        NAME.no/privkey.pem;

        # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
            $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:82/;
            proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location = /wordpress {
            return https://SERVER-NAME.no/NEXT-JS-BLOG-PAGE;
        }

        location /wordpress/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
            $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://IP.TO-WORDPRESS:8000/;
            # proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

### Expected:

I would expect urls to work both in the wordpress admin panel and for the wordpress posts and rss feed. This is not the case.

Please help as I'm quite lost on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem was in the Wordpress app and not with the Nginx configuration. Turns out Wordpress has something called wp_admin_canonical_url() that sets the url in addition to siteurl and home.

See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269798/wrong-wp-admin-url.